# Angular JS Javascript animation fadeIn doesnt work for newly added items

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fadein, ng-animate

I have section of html which displays items in a list with a certain structure. I want to fadeIn the newly pushed items in to the `$scope` list based on some user interaction. I am using the `$animate` service and `ngAnimate` is injected into the app.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker',['ngAnimate'])
.animation('.esnfadein',function(){
    return{
          enter:function(element,done){
              jQuery(element).fadeIn(800,function(){
              done;
              });
          },        

          leave:function(element,done){
              jQuery(element).fadeIn(800,function(){
              done;
              });
          }
     };
});
```

The class is applied to html as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="esnfadein">...</div>
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2e7lOBHZKbi4a6coWojp?p=preview) of the working code. Fadein is not working while fadeOut works fine. Am i missing something here which applies specifically to Javascript animations in angular JS?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think ngShow might help you?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) only works on elements with `display:none`, so you should `.hide()` them before applying the `fadeIn` effect.

Also, you weren't calling the `done` function -- it was missing the `()`. However, as that is the only thing you are doing in the callback, it is easier to pass it as the callback to the fade animations.

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jhXNacF4CoZpShHNsNZC?p=preview)

```
app.animation('.esnfadein',function(){
  return{
    enter: function(element,done){
      jQuery(element).hide().fadeIn(800, done);
    },
    leave: function(element,done){
      jQuery(element).fadeOut(800, done);
    }
  };
});
```

---

Note: it is also possible to do this without any jQuery, using CSS3 Transitions. There's an example in the [animations docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations) ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cqcaiZhinJoCumLgdpb0?p=preview)).

Comment: Cool! Thanks. Definitely did not know about the fadeIn working for display:none elements. But if a new element is being created, dont you think by default it has display:none? I mean it is not yet available in DOM.

Comment: @frisco_1989 while the element is detached from the DOM, it has no [computed CSS values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value). But when it is appended to the DOM, the browser's default style sheet and your style sheets' rules (and the [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) properties, if any) are applied to that element. At that point, the `div` in your plunker has `display:block` (from the browser's default style sheet), and only then your animation code runs.